# Issue with overriding MongoCollection::update

Tags: php, oop, mongodb, inheritance, overriding

I'm running the following version of PHP: PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 28 2012 18:19:13).

I have a class which inherits from \MongoGridFS:

```
class PdfGrid extends \MongoGridFS {
// ...

public function update( array $criteria , array $new_object, array $options = array()){
    $options['safe'] = true;
    if ( isset($criteria['_id']) && ! $criteria['_id'] instanceof \MongoId){
        $criteria['_id'] = new \MongoId($criteria['_id']);
    }
    return parent::update($criteria, $new_object, $options);
}
}
```

Whenever I run a script that uses this class, I get the following error:

> PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of YS\MongoCollection\PdfGrid::update() should be compatible with that of MongoCollection::update() in /Users/js/dev/YsInv/lib/YS/MongoCollection/PdfGrid.php on line 68

But alas, the definition matches precisely with what appears on php.net for \MongoCollection::update:

> public bool|array MongoCollection::update ( array $criteria , array $new_object [, array $options = array() ] )

Comment: It is normally better advice to wrap these object rather than extend them

Comment: Don't trust the docs look at the locally hosted definition of MongoCollection::update(). The documentation is likely stale.