# Declaration of Class::save() should be compatible with that of Class::save()

Tags: php, mongodb, extending

I am extending the MongoCollection Class and I am getting this message.

> Declaration of Db\Mongo\Collection::save() should be compatible with that of MongoCollection::save()

I understand that this is normally a pram declaration miss match.

Php.net says the prams are:

> public mixed save ( array|object $a [, array $options = array() ] )

I have tried all the following to fix this problem:

```
public function save(array &$a, array $options = array())
public function save($a, array $options = array())
public function save(&$a, array $options = array())
public function save($a, $options = array())
public function save($a = array(), $options = array())
```

And many others and I can NOT seem to be able to match the type.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this error? How do you declare a pram as array|object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this error

> Strict Standards: Declaration of MyMongoCollection::save() should be
>   compatible with MongoCollection::save($array_of_fields_OR_object,
>   array $options = NULL)

So I tried:

```
class MyMongoCollection extends MongoCollection {

    public function save($arr_obj, array $options= null) {

    }

}
```

and it works.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you can get any information on the `MongoCollection::save()` method using the [`ReflectionClass`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php):

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass( 'MongoCollection' );

foreach ( $reflection->getMethod('save')->getParameters() as $param )
{ 
    var_dump( $param->getName(), $param->isArray(), $param->isOptional() ); 
}
```

to get the missing pieces, in the case the documentation is not up to date?

ps: this is a slightly modified code example taken from [this ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-308).

It looks like there are similar problems extending `update` method of the `MongoGridFS` extension of the `MongoCollection` class:

[Issue with overriding MongoCollection::update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490297/issue-with-overriding-mongocollectionupdate)

Comment: Thanks a lot. End up with this ugly interface: https://gist.github.com/clslrns/c64d7c1c3bd5bbc6b012

Comment: @VitalyChirkov thanks for sharing that gist snippet.